# Xamarin Java Binding Library - Sinch

Tags: java, api, binding, xamarin, sinch

I am having issues creating a java binding library in Xamarin from the Sinch Android API. It seems like its not linking all the class files contained in the jar file.

```
obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.ConfigRefresher.cs(9,87,9,121): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UserAgentMethodInvocationScheduler' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client.HouseKeeper.cs(9,83,9,117): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UserAgentMethodInvocationScheduler' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sinch.Android.Rtc.Internal.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Rebtel.Repackaged.Com.Google.Gson.Internal.Bind.TypeAdapters.cs(942,25,942,30): error CS0111: Type 'Com.Rebtel.Repackaged.Com.Google.Gson.Internal.Bind.TypeAdapters.EnumTypeAdapter' already defines a member called 'Write' with the same parameter types
```

I am using the 3.4.1 Android API here:
https://www.sinch.com/downloads/

Comment: try closing and opening Xamarin studio, there is a bug where it sometimes doesn't load the references until the solution is reloaded.

Comment: I'll try that tonight. Were you able to sucessfully build the Sinch API I listed above using Xamarin?

Comment: Still having issues with java bindings in Xamarin. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, We havent tried using xamarin, did you manage to get it working?

Comment: No, I did not. If you guys could provide Xamarin support that would be wonderful!

Comment: do you have a contact in xamarin support, maybe you could connect us and we could try and work it out

Comment: @Jman Were you able to get it working?

Comment: I'd also be very happy if this could be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I am using sinch binding from https://github.com/NAXAM/sinch-verification-android-binding.

Point to be noted: if you directly add reference from above GitHub link into your project you will get lot of compile time error .

**Use Nuget package instead** 
**Install-Package Naxam.SinchVerification.Droid**

It works fine .